# WordPress Plugin Install Asks for FTP Details

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, ftp, credentials

WordPress is asking me for my SFTP credentials in order to install any plugins.

I am using Linux ubuntu 12.**.

But Same thing I tried on Window "Wamp" server. I can install plugins.

Can Any one know why this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried this, I am able to work with this solution

Please use in  wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

This statement solve my issue.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it's working for me as well. Good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I still had problems when the files were hosted on a different location than on my web server. So, just for reference, if you choose to use ftp.. you can add these lines to your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your file permissions are set.

Check your wordpress login has admin rights.

You may be behind a proxy, so when wordpress does a curl request to get the code it fails. I am guessing your linux firewall may be blocking it where as your windows isn't.

Comment: I have tried to change file permission then I am facing same issue